# merge with multiple tables

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I have a problem with reshaping the data; following is an example dataset I have.

```
x<-data.frame(SN=rep(1:4,c(3,3,4,4)),value=1:14,F=rep(c(LETTERS[1:4]), each = 1, len =  14))
```

I need to recreate the data with column containing data for unique SN and then assign column name with that SN in 'value' to identify SN. Finally, I need to merge them together.

I want the following output:

```
F   1   2   3   4    
A   1   5   9   13
B   2   6   10  14
C   3   NA  7   11
D   NA  4   8   12
```

Structure of my data is:

```
SN : Chr "1.1", 100.1", "100.5" ...
F:  Factor w/24 levels ...
value: num ...
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Neither example generates an error, but both generate warnings due to repeated column names. Can you provide a precise description of what your expected output is?

Comment: @joran and all, I have edited the question. Thanks for offering the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, as with the other posters I am pretty unsure of what you are asking but this is my interpretation of what you are trying to do:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast( x , F ~ SN , value.var = "value" )
#  F 1 2  3  4
#1 A 1 5  9 13
#2 B 2 6 10 14
#3 C 3 0  7 15
#4 D 0 4  8 12
```

Unique SN is column names, rows are F and the values are the corresponding values found in the value column. However, if there are more than one value for the SN-F combination (as for SN = 4 and F = C where you have 11 and 15) it takes the `max` value.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I did this pretty blindly just trying to automate your manual process but I think it works. If your data is quite big then there are definitely ways to improve the speed of the make.sub() function, but I'm guessing that isn't an issue for you.

```
#make funciton to make your subsets
make.sub <- function(sn){
  tmp <- x[x$SN==sn,]
  names(tmp)[2] <- sn
  return(tmp)
}

#apply function to get list of subsets
x.list <- lapply(unique(SN), make.sub)

#merge list of subsets
x.merged <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="F"), x.list)
```

As you can see this gives the same result as your manual process.

```
> x.merged
  F SN.x 1 SN.y 2 SN.x  3 SN.y  4
1 A    1 1    2 5    3  9    4 13
2 B    1 2    2 6    3 10    4 14
> x_all
  F SN.x 1 SN.y 2 SN.x  3 SN.y  4
1 A    1 1    2 5    3  9    4 13
2 B    1 2    2 6    3 10    4 14
```

Comment: use `x.list = split(x, x$SN)` instead

Comment: definitely a cleaner method than the messy function I wrote, but since I didn't really understand the ultimate goal I wanted to make sure to change the 2nd variable name as demonstrated in the manual example.

Comment: @David, it works fine in the above dataset. But when I applied in my data, it gives following error:
    Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid column(s)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your task, but I hope this code works:

```
x<-data.frame(SN=rep(1:4,c(3,3,4,5)),value=1:15,F=rep(c(LETTERS[1:4]), each = 1, len = 15))

SN<-unique(x$SN)
for (i in 1:length(SN)){
  xi<-x[x$SN==SN[i],]  
  colnames(xi)[2]<-paste("SN",i,sep=".")
  xi<-xi[,c(3,2)]
  if (i==1){x_all<-xi}
  if (i>1){
  x_all<-merge(x_all,xi,by="F")
  }
}
head(x_all)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry for not being clearer earlier. My SNs in the real dataset are not only numbers; so I can't use logical operators before merging.